# Is the method/function responsible for validate your call?

Tags: architecture, semantics

Why is best way to write a function/method?

1 - First way

```
function main() {
     back()
}

function back() {
    if(step > 0) {
          step = step - 1
     }
}
```

2 - Second Way

```
function main() {
    if(step > 0) {
          back()
     }
}

function back() {
    step = step - 1
}
```

I think that the second option is the best way because the function back do only one thing... that is back. But, what you think be the right way and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must encapsulate the browsing behavior in a class responsible for it.

Second, you should follow the Tell-Don't-Ask principle, in this case, the first option

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Answer (score 1):

The second one. Consider the first alternative. At the point of calling `back()`, someone reading your code is unable to tell that the `if` check is performed. It gives a poor overview of what is actually going on. The back function should in that case be called `backIfNeeded` which smells of poor programming design.

In short, the second alternative provides better overview and simpler execution flow.